# Validate list modification in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider the following sqlalchemy model that validates the `primary_email` field:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableList

Base = declarative_base()

class Test(Base):
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    primary_email = Column(String(128))

    @validates('primary_email')
    def valid_email(self, key, value):
        if not '@' in value:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid {key}: '{value}'")
        return value
        
    def __init__(self, email):
        primary_email = email
```

It works as expected but now I want to add another column

```
secondary_email = Column(MutableList.as_mutable(postgresql.ARRAY(String(128))))
```

How do I perform validation on `secondary_email.append(email)` call?

When I add `'secondary_email'` to `validates` decorator, it only gets triggered on assignment operations like

```
self.secondary_email = ['example@me.com']
```

I believe this is something that can be achieved with a custom class but I wonder if there is a simpler and more generic solution?